# Swipe left/right for MOBILE on Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I tried to add swipe left/right to a Bootstrap Carousel Slider with jquery, but it doesn't work. Here's my code :

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$(".carousel").swipe({

  swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {

    if (direction == 'left') $(this).carousel('next');
    if (direction == 'right') $(this).carousel('prev');

  },
  allowPageScroll:"vertical"

});
```

I want to add that I also tried using jquery mobile script from the official page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn't work to swipe the images anyway I have tried.
Scripts that I use on my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap carousel jQuery error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928631/bootstrap-carousel-jquery-error)

Comment: Is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to enable it:

```
$("#carousel-example-generic").carousel();

$(".item").click(function(){
$("#carousel-example-generic").carousel(1);
});

$(".left carousel-control").click(function(){
$("#carousel-example-generic").carousel("prev");
});

$(".right carousel-control").click(function(){
    $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel("next");
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write out my javascript code that I am using. I tried your code too, but no result :(

Comment: It doesn't work, even with your code edit. Do you know any other solution to the problem? Thx anyway.

Comment: It works fine, check the link: (https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUWDWVQCD2RX)

Comment: Yes, it works, but I need Swipe on mobile devices for the carousel, not just with the arrows or the bullet points.